# Do Docker's debug and experimental flags have a performance impact?

Tags: performance, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

If I turn off Docker Daemon `debug` and `experimental` flags, would it increase performance on macOS?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this won't be a clear yes or no answer, but *generally*, I don't believe you will see noticeable changes in performance of Docker with these flags on or off.

The `debug` flag in Docker mainly controls log output. There are not additional codepaths that get added to the daemon, so unless log writing in that environment has a significant slowdown (e.g. disk performance), again, I don't think the debug flag will have any noticeable impact.

The `experimental` flag **could** potentially have impact, but this flag's impact will change each release or even point release depending on what is "behind" the experimental feature flag. Usually it is a new feature (command, option, configuration) that by enabling it should not have impact on the rest of daemon operations.  That said, it isn't impossible to consider a case where an experimental feature does change the codepaths of other parts of the daemon, but generally I don't think this is the case, but is hard to predict as new features may come in the future that do impact performance.